# Sending mail with php

Tags: php, email

What do I need to install prior to be able to send email with PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted out. I had to download the pear modules and include them in the working directory

Answer (score 2):

you have to configure "**[mail function]**" section in **php.ini**.

First of all you have to have SMTP support for send&receive e-mails.
Second, you have to configure "SMTP" and "smtp_port" values in php.ini file.

Comment: So that means that I would only be able to have one mail server per php installation?